# JWT enabled Spring Security configuration to permit all requests to Swagger UI

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, jwt, amazon-cognito

I have the following JWT configuration, However I want to permitAll requests to my swagger ui
I have tried to add antMatcher  with permitAll(), but no success.

Can someone help me with that ?

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class JwtAuthConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(getJwtAuthenticationConverter());
    }

    private Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> getJwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        JwtAuthenticationConverter converter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        converter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwt -> {
            Map<String, Object> claims = jwt.getClaims();
            String userType = (String) claims.get("custom:userType");
            Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
            if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(userType))
                grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + userType));
            return grantedAuthorities;
        });
        return converter;
    }
}
```

I have this REST prefix defined as well:

```
server:
  port: 5000
  servlet:
    context-path: /api/v1
```

Comment: Do you have logs errors ?? For instance, if you are not setting a JWT in your call from swagger, maybe jwt.getClaims() can lead to a NPE, that can be an scenario.

Comment: @JuanBC As a first step I just want UI to be load without letting it to do REST calls,
but "/api/v1/swagger-ui.html" gives  an "unauthorized" error

Comment: Can you post please the AntMatcher that you have already tried ??

Comment: @JuanBC I have added 
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**swagger**/**")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(getJwtAuthenticationConverter());

Comment: Now it gives 404...
I have added dependencies and config with @EnableSwagger2
should it be on /api/v1/swagger-ui.html ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you need something like this:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers("/swagger/**").permitAll()
  ...
```

Looks like you still need to make sure the other requests are authenticated using the oauth filter. Take a look at the .authenticated() example here:
[Oauth Filter Spring](https://curity.io/resources/tutorials/howtos/writing-apis/spring-boot-api/)